# setdiff in r is not pulling subset of data

Tags: r, subset, set-difference

I have two data frames: `raw2` which has 28,406 records and `raw3` 26,421 records.

The records in `raw3` are a subset of those in `raw2`. In fact `raw3` was derived using:

```
raw3<-setDT(raw2)[order(O_ID, Program_forsorting), head(.SD, 1), .(O_ID)]
```

I now have a `setdiff` function where I'm trying to pull the records that did not get carried over from `raw2` to `raw3` using:

```
settdiff(raw2,raw3)
```

The results should have 1,985 records. However, the results have 28,406 which represents `raw2`. If I switch the formula around to `settdiff(raw3,raw2)` the results contains 26,421 records.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is sample data

```
raw2<-as.data.frame(cbind("col1"=c("a","h","b","f","g"),"O_ID"=c(1,1,1,4,5), "Program_forsorting"=c("p1","p2","p2","p3","p1")))
```

Comment: Are there multiple columns? Are you trying to check that all values in all columns match? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You don't have to share your actual data, but unless we can reproduce what's going on, it's not easy to help.

Comment: I didn't provide sample data initially since I thought it was associated with the size of the dataset. I've provided sample data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted a response and then deleted it. However, it works so I'll share here.

If data goes over multiple columns I should have used the `fsetdiff` function.

```
fsettdiff(raw2,raw3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe `setdiff` works on datatables directly since it takes a vector for input... you'd have to create a function and apply over all columns. I'd try using the native datatable function `fsetdiff`. Make sure both objects are datatable objects.

```
fsetdiff(raw2,raw3)
```